# How to monitor all live traffic on linux server?

Tags: server

I hosted a lot of websites on "Linux" server and I want to see live how many visitors I have on all websites hosted on same server.

P.S I want to use Arduino Uno screen to see live traffic on server.

Comment: you need to query that info from your web server. Apache: http://askubuntu.com/questions/239631/how-can-i-watch-the-current-connections-on-my-apache-webserver   NginX: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/nginx-see-active-connections-connections-per-seconds/

Answer (score 0):

If you have cpanel/Plesk control panel, you can get an access to the AWstats wherein you can explore the traffic to all your websites. In case, you are using a different control panel, you will need to install AWstats.